# How to move elements

Tags: python, element

I know this question has been asked many times. When I search I normally get answers relating to swapping elements in a list.

I am not looking to swap elements in a list, rather to move elements, from one position to another.

example (moving element 0:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

output:

```
[2,3,1,4,5]
```

example (moving element 2):

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

output:

```
[1,2,4,5,3]
```

Is there an inbuilt python function that can allow me to do that?

P.S I am not asking for u guys to show me how to do this... I am asking for if there is an inbult function in python !!!!!!!

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: The only thing I can think of is swapping elements... u see I am fairly new at programming... how can I try anything if I first don't learn about it??

Comment: because a simple google search will give you endless results for a question like this. try researching and experimenting yourself. Asking a question on SO should always be a last resort :)

Comment: @samrap, Indeed. And in my research I feel that swapping elements is the most popular method of changing the position of elements. So there is no inbuilt function that changes the position of an element other than swapping??

Comment: There's no builtin function.  You're not swapping, of course: in both examples you're doing a cyclic permutation, of a prefix (example 1) or suffix (example 2) of the list.

Comment: cyclic permutation, humm thats interesting.. I should look it up.

Comment: for the record I never voted you down, I was just making a suggestion as you are new to SO.

Comment: @samrap .. oh yeah, no thats not a problem.. in the real world its not these virtual votes that will count, rather knowledge that is acquired and put into practical use(as that is the intrinsic value of knowledge) ... Thats why we all are here aren't we? Not for the votes but for the knowledge !

Comment: @user2954367, ya, "cyclic permutation" is highfalutin' ;-) Most folks would probably call it "rotating".

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it is not entirely clear what the precise function is that you are looking for, so here are a few functions that should achieve whatever transformation you're looking for.

Here is a function that can swap the value at position x in a list for the value at position y, and vice versa.

```
def swap(mylist, x, y):
    """Swaps position x for position y in a list"""
    swap1 = mylist[x]
    swap2 = mylist[y]
    mylist[y] = swap1
    mylist[x] = swap2
    return mylist
```

Here is a function that moves the value at position x, y positions forward.

```
def moveforward(mylist, x, y):
    """"Function moves the value at position x, y positions forward, keeping x in its     original position"""
    move1 = mylist[x]
    mylist[x + y] = move1
    return mylist
```

Here is a function to rotate every value from x onwards one value forward, moving the value at the end of the list to x.

```
def rotate(mylist, x):
     """Rotates all values from x onwards one value forward, moving the end of the list to x."""

    replace = x + 1
    while replace < len(mylist):
        mylist[replace] = mylist[replace - 1]
        replace += 1

    mylist[x] = mylist[replace - 1]

    return mylist
```

Finally:

```
def rotateback(mylist, x, y):
    """Rotates every value beyond x one back and places value mylist[x] at position mylist[y]""".

    xx = mylist[x]

    while x < y:
        mylist[x] = mylist[x + 1]
        x += 1

    mylist[y] = xx


    return mylist
```

Comment: Hello Michael, thanks for the prompt answer ! .. but that is the problem I am not looking to swap the integers in a list, rather move them ...

Comment: It really depends on how you want to move them, i.e. you need to define where value x moves to. Ultimately what you are describing is a series of swaps/replacements. If you define what moves where, it's easy to write a function.

Comment: so for example I want x to always move 3 spaces forward... in any given list... I would want to create a code that would work for all types of list that include x.

Comment: Ok, I've added a function `moveforward` that will do that. Call `moveforward(mylist, x, 3) to move x three positions forward.

Comment: So `moveforward` duplicates the element at index `x` and overwrite the element at index `x+y`?

Comment: Yes (extra text to be allowed to post).

Comment: From your question, it's not entirely clear what you're looking for, so I've added a final function what will rotate every value forward by one and move the end of the list to x. These three functions should be able to achieve whatever change to the list you'd like to do.

Comment: Thank you very much Michael ! for taking out the time to write all these functions. My question was to move an element inside a list, some positions forward or backward... so if I have the index = [1,2,3,4,5] and I want to move [2], three positions forward my final output should be x=[1,3,4,5,2]

Comment: Ok, I believe `rotateback` should do what you want.

Comment: @Michael You know that your first version is a one-liner: `mylist [x], mylist [y] = mylist [y], mylist [x]`. No need for temporary variables...

Comment: @Hyperboreus I agree, though sometimes the simplest solution is not the clearest to a new user.

Answer (score 0):

Something along this line maybe:

```
def move (iter, from_, to):
    iter.insert (to, iter.pop (from_) )
```

Comment: seems like this might do the trick... but one question, does this .pop method take the element out from the list then adds it again. like erase and print?

Comment: Yes, it takes the element out of the list and then `insert` inserts it again at the desired position.

Comment: @user2954367 The element is removed from the list after it is returned(printed).

Comment: okay how about elements that are near the end? for example index = [1,2,3,4,5] ... so if I want to move 5 a space forward it wont work because 5 is at the end?

Comment: And what should be where the `5` was before? A hole?